# How do I switch off "continuous" mode permanently in Evince?

Tags: settings, default, evince

this is an FAQ on the website for Evince but without any answer. I searched gconf but with no luck. Even on a per document basis, Evince won't remember this setting! I want it to be off. Any help on this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Open a multi page document and disable it in

> View / Continuous

Then try

> Edit / Save current settings as default

If that still doesn't do it, you need to install **dconf Editor** and find the settings below, in

> org / gnome / evince / default

I un-checked 'continuous' and it seems to work. I tested a few different PDFs and most worked as expected, without continuous mode. A couple did, but this may be because I had used the first method when changing something else.

Try it and comment again if it still doesn't solve it for you.

[image: dconf-Editor config]

Comment: This doesn't work. I've done this, but when opening a _new_ pdf, "continous" is checked again.

Comment: Bummer, it's marked as a 'fixed' bug here on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/evince/+bug/180933 and here on Gnome.org: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316962. Maybe file another bug? I wasn't aware of this 'continuous mode' option before but I like it better, hope it gets fixed again.

Comment: Great the dconf-editor (in dconf-tools package) approach is working. Thanks! Can you remove the lines before your edit? I think if you say something to Bug in the answer and provide this workaround, the answer would be best possible so far. :D

Comment: Done, have a look. I'll leave my comment above because it links back to the bug reports. Thanks for making me aware of this, browsing PDFs is now much faster!

Comment: Great, yes. :-D

Comment: sadly the custom settings ignore is a known bug in evince, still persistent. I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 3.13 on 08/2014 and this behaviour isn't fixed yet. I changed my default document viewer, since it's a 5 years old bug. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=639003#c17

Answer (score 2):

Edit file */usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Evince.gschema.xml* and 
look for they key with name `continuous`. Change the default to `false`.