# Where are the case sensitive and whole words search options in Evince document viewer?

Tags: evince

In [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) document viewer I can search for text in a document using the find option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). However, I can't find where to activate the *Case Sensitive* and *Whole Words Only* search options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the left side of the search box there is a magnifier icon. If you click on it, it will display a drop down menu where you can activate the *Case Sensitive* and *Whole Words Only* search options.

[image: case sensitive and whole words search in Evince]

Comment: If the purpose was to hide these options very well, they've succeeded. Fortunately, [@codeaviator](https://askubuntu.com/users/643185) saved my day.

Comment: I agree @twigmac. There is a lack of obvious hints to find these options easily. This is what motivated me to post this self-answered question, to help folks like you and my future self. Cheers :)

Comment: Any way to permanently set this setting? I have to right-click and turn it on every new instance. From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84631) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013853/756725) there are some config files, but they don't seem to deal with search.

Comment: I don't have the 'whole words only' option with a .djvu file.